# how can I display saved values from the database to wysiwyg tinymce

Tags: php, laravel-5, wysiwyg

Apparently, I can't use

```
<div>
  <label for="description">Description</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" id="description"  name="description" rows="3" value="{{ $product->description }}"></textarea>
</div>
```

now that I am using a WYSIWYG(tinymce), it works with `textarea` alone but with WYSIWYG integrated in a `textarea`, No. How can I show the value of the `description` in a WYSIWYG? do I have to use Javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<textarea>` doesn't have a `value` attribute. Put contents between the tags:

```
<div>
  <label for="description">Description</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" id="description"  name="description" rows="3">
    {{ $product->description }}
  </textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad it works. Feel free to accept this as answer ;)

Comment: yep, I will, I am just waiting for the time. I can't accept answers for another 1 minute haha